# Which is more Efficient array.forEach or angular.forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

### array.prototype.forEach

`forEach()` executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

### angular.forEach

Invokes the iterator function once for each item in obj collection, which can be either an object or an array. The iterator function is invoked with iterator(value, key, obj), where value is the value of an object property or an array element, key is the object property key or array element index and obj is the obj itself. Specifying a context for the function is optional.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

But I want to know which one is more efficient and the performance.

Comment: Array#forEach works without library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AngularJS forEach used to implement ES5 forEach if available, which was not the fastest, but since this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3221) it is using the fastest for loop.

https://angularjs.de/buecher/angularjs-cookbook/es5-array-functions

> *If you look at this [comparison](http://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-loop/20), you see, that the **ES5 forEach implementation is not the fastest**. The AngularJS version in this
>   comparison uses ES5 forEach, if it’s available. This is changed by
>   this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3221). **Now it’s always using the fastest for loop**.*

- https://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/148

Comment: The site is in maintenance can you give me any other link.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150909085855/http://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/141

Comment: @bfmags , are you **sure** it's using ES5 forEach? Looking at the source code for v1.5.7 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.7/src/Angular.js#L237 Line 248 in particular is interesting. If the object is an array, it does *not* use any native `forEach` function. It's instead using a `for` loop. Only if the object is *not* an array (or array-like), will execution flow to line 255 which will rely on a `forEach` function on the object.

Comment: @Snixtor Updated! It used to use ES5 forEach if available, but now it’s always using the fastest for loop. thnx!

Comment: @rittam The community (me and bfmags) have worked together to craft a quality answer to your question. It's been upvoted a few times, meaning that others think it is a useful answer. You should consider marking it as 'the answer', or clarify why you don't think it answers your question.